# XSLT grouping table rows

Tags: xslt

I have this table (done with CSS div{display:table;})

```
     <div class="wl">
     <div><div><p>text 1</p></div><div><p>text a</p></div></div>
     <div><div><p>text 2</p></div><div><p>text b</p></div></div>
     <div><div><p>text 3</p></div><div><p>text c</p></div></div>
     <div class="indent"><div><p>text 4</p></div><div><p>text d</p></div></div>
     <div><div><p>text 5</p></div><div><p>text e</p></div></div>
     </div>
```

based on the fact that the class="indent" row immediately follows the previous row, I want these two rows merged (and tabled) as follows:

```
     <table>
     <tr><td><p>text 1</p></td><td><p>text a</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><p>text 2</p></td><td><p>text b</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><p>text 3</p><p>text 4</p></td><td><p>text b</p><p>text d</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><p>text 5</p></td><td><p>text e</p></td></tr>
     </table>
```

Experimenting got me this far, which obviously does not work yet:

```
    <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]">
<table>
<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::following-sibling/@class='indent1')" >
    <tr>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="div">
    <td>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

it gives me just the first row. I have the feeling this cannot be done with grouping, because the group cannot be identified with some key, only by the class name of the following element.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Your sample output has "text b" twice and "text c" not at all. Is the second "text b" supposed to say "text c"?

Comment: yes. sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

First-glance obvious error: Change `self::following-sibling` to `following-sibling::div`. You want the next `<div>` sibling, not "this node if it is a `<following-sibling>`"

Comment: +1. And not only that, but you only want the very next `<div>` sibling (singular), not all following-sibling::div elements. So, `following-sibling::div[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply push the nodes through the right templates when I process the `div` transformed to be `td` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div[@class = 'indent']" priority="5"/>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div/div">
  <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div[following-sibling::*[1][self::div[@class = 'indent']]]/div" priority="5">
  <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>
  <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() , ../following-sibling::*[1][self::div[@class = 'indent']]/div[position() = $pos]/node()"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As Tobias has rightly pointed out in a comment, it is possible to eliminate one template and simply push any following sibling stuff if it exists:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div[@class = 'indent']" priority="5"/>

<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div/div">
  <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>
  <td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() , ../following-sibling::*[1][self::div[@class = 'indent']]/div[position() = $pos]/node()"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need that last template, you can just put its content inside the `<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]/div/div">`. If there is no directly following div with indent it will not apply anyways.

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz, you are right, I have edited and provided a second sample implementing that change.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with grouping, along the lines you are currently attempting, but your **xsl:for-each-group** probably needs to look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="div" group-starting-with="div[not(@class='indent')]">
```

Then, to get the elements that make up each cell in the row, you would replace your current **xsl:apply-templates** with this:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/div[position()=$pos]/*" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]">
        <table>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="div" group-starting-with="div[not(@class='indent')]">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="div">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/div[position()=$pos]/*" />
                    </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: nice. The counter is a bit ugly, but I don't see a way (yet?) to eliminate it. Next thing is to give <p>text 4</p> and <p>text d</p> both class='indent'. But maybe that would be better done in CSS (not(first-child)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your energy. 
I'm new to XSLT, as you must be aware of now, and reading up on XSLT like crazy.
Your input is educating.
With your help, I found this solution:

```
<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'wl')]">
  <table>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="node()[not(contains(@class , 'indent'))]" >
  <tr>
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <p><xsl:value-of select="node()[1]"/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
      <p><xsl:value-of select="node()[2]"/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```